# Insert Hour value like 50 hour in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i like to assign hour to the student for his course, when he attend the class hour will deduct
amount of class duration time.can any body help   **how to insert time in hour like 50-hour and perform operation on this like add 30 minutes, 1 hour in mysql database?**

Comment: Create an integer column to keep track of time spent in minutes: it's easy enough to format to hours:minutes when you need to display it as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Datime as the column name and then use MYSQL functions such as SELECT DATE_SUB(column, INTERVAL X HOUR) Please refer DATE_SUB for more details

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub

Comment: you can, but IMHO you shouldn't.  MySQL's `DATETIME` type is intended to represent a specific absolute moment in time, not relative times.

Comment: @Alnitak: true, but all records can have same reference in time; and if you subtract that reference from record, you get the amount of relative time. But yes, this all depends on OP's design.

Answer (score 0):

Do not put the answer in a datetimefield - that is only for specific dates and times (such as February 1, 2012 10:42 EST).

If you are storing a quantity of anything (oranges, dollars, hours), make it an int - or if you need fractional, a decimal.

In your case, I'd store the number of minutes in an int. When you want to convert back to hours or fractional hours, your application code can do it easily. Finally, make sure the name of the column reflects what it is: in this case, I'd suggest classduration_mins. That way you won't forget what units you are using.